# Insert into sql in PHP

Tags: php, comments

Lets say I have a file called `comments.php`. In it I have a row like this:

```
$post_id = $_GET['id']; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = $post_id");
```

`$post_id` is the id of the actual entry.

If I echo `$post_id` it shows the entry's number, no problem there.

There's also a file called `comment_send.php`.

In it I want to send a comment, alongside with the id of the actual entry, so the comments will know where they belong to.

```
$post_id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = $post_id"); 
$sql="INSERT INTO comments (comment, post_id) VALUES ('$_GET[comment]','$post_id')";
```

However, when I hit the submit button I get this: `Notice: Undefined index: id`

I dont understand the problem because in the `comments.php` everything works fine but if I move the same part into another file it fails. Does anyone know what my problem might be?

And yeah, the comment arrives in the database, with the number 0, instead of the entry number.

Comment: Did you even try to search?

Comment: Your url should be: comment_send.php?id=23&comment='This is a comment'

Comment: You know you are open to SQL injection, right?  Either use prepared statements or typecast your ID to an interger.

Comment: comment_send.php?comment=This a comment  This is the url

Comment: ack SQL Injection!!!  Do not do this!

Comment: Then is wrong....the url should be like this one comment_send.php?id=23&comment='This is a comment'

Comment: try to have a input hidden with the id value in you submit form

Comment: This is how I did it: <input type="hidden" value="$post_id"  name="postid"/> Still doesnt work :/

Comment: IT WORKS WITH THE HIDDEN FORM TRICK. Thank you guys, but it's still GET, is that a huge problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your submitting data from the client to the server using a form, right?  Check your action on your form.  Is it POST (as it should be if you are updating your database)?  If so, change `$post_id = $_GET['id'];` to `$post_id = $_POST['id'];`

As a troubleshooting tool, I typically add something like `echo('<pre>'.print_r($_REQUEST,1).'</pre>');` to the top of my page. You can then find out what type of data you are sending to the server.  Then when you get to your SQL statement, be sure to echo the query to see what it is.

Also, sanitize your data as you are open to SQL injection.

Comment: Yes I use a simple form with get method to submit the comments.

Comment: Well I changed to POST but I get 2 errors even at the comments.php

Comment: @user2258123.  What errors?  Notice: Undefined index: id?  If so, this has nothing to do with your SQL.  You are trying to read an index in an array ($_POST or $_GET or what ever) which doesn't exist.  That is why you should echo the array first using $_PRINT_R() to find out which indexes are set.  What is the output of $_PRINT_R($_POST,1)?  Do the same with $_GET.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean here, yes I get the undefined index error, but if I chanege them back to GET, it works fine. dont you know how to put $post_id into a form? I get $post_id instead of it's value. <input type="text" value=<?php $post_id ?> name="postid"/> I use text to see whats in it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are passing 'id' to your comment_send.php page.  Either pass it in with your comment, or save it as a $_SESSION variable on the previous page.